# Shared SBT module in Intellij Idea without publish-local

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

SBT project `A` depends on `B`. Both projects have separate VCS repositories and have own lifecycle, including automated building and testing.

Is there a way to work with these projects *conveniently* in Intellij Idea?

By *conveniently*, I mostly mean:

- CMD-Click points to actual, editable classes between projects, no read-only published jar
- No need to run `sbt publish-local` every time a change is made
- Breakpoints work as expected

Looks like all this is not possible if dependency is declared simply as `libraryDependencies`. However, declaring relationship with relative paths would fail build systems.

Comment: Should be able to import both projects, then replace the dependency to point to the local project within the ide project model

Comment: @pfn SBT auto-import feature drops manually set dependency. As well as manual import restores module dependencies back to SBT configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a limitation of the sbt structure plugin in intellij.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

In `Project A` created a file `local-dependencies.sbt` (the name not important) with the following contents:

```
libraryDependencies ~= {l => l.filter(_.name != "my-utils")}
lazy val utils = RootProject(file("../my-utils"))
lazy val root = Project(id = "ProjectA", base = file(".")).dependsOn(utils)
```

The first line excludes `my-utils` from `libraryDependencies` defined in `build.sbt` which is needed for automated builds.

Now `Project A` has `my-utils` as *Module* dependency, and  *not Library* dependency, which addresses the mentioned issues.

Note, that `local-dependencies.sbt` is for local env only and should be ignored in VCS, e.g.:

```
$ cat .hgignore

local-dependencies.sbt
```

Comment: Is it possible to refer to a module of the other project?

Answer (score 0):

Create IntelliJ Scala sbt Project `A`.

Then open `build.sbt` and enter:

```
name := "A"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.7"

lazy val b = (project in file("B"))

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
   .aggregate(b)
   .dependsOn(b)
```

and save this. When asked "sbt projects need to be imported" in a small dialog box at the right bottom corner, select "Enable Auto-Import".

IntelliJ now creates the subfolder B **automatically**, and places a `target` subfolder therein. In subfolder `B`, create a new `build.sbt` for `B` containing:

```
sourceDirectory in Compile := (baseDirectory( _ / "src" )).value
```

After save, create new directories `B/src/scala`. 
Open Tool Window for `sbt` (Menu: View -> Tool Windows -> sbt). Click "Refresh all sbt projects" icon.

Add your library scala Files into `B/src/scala`.

Now You have a multi module project, consisting out of main module A, depending on library sub-module B.